# Dynamic data binding with bootstrap tabs on onclick event in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

Hello i am using bootstrap tabs and slick slider inside that in angular 2 
here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="tab-heading">Short Films</li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" (click)="shortLatest()">Latest</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" (click)="shortMostLiked()">Most Liked</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" (click)="shortMostWatched()">Most Watched</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 20px;">

    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <!--<slick-slider-three class="slick-slider">
        Hello
      </slick-slider-three>-->
      <div *ngIf="shortfilmslatest">
        <slick-slider-three class="slick-slider">
          <div *ngFor="let film of shortfilmslatest">
            <img [src]="film.banner" alt="Banner">
          </div>
        </slick-slider-three>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!shortfilmslatest">
        <!-- Pre load -->
          <loader></loader>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">

      <!--<slick-slider-three [shortfilms]=tag></slick-slider-three>-->
      <!--<h3>Most Liked</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>-->
      <div *ngIf="shortmostliked">
        <slick-slider-three class="slick-slider">
          <div *ngFor="let liked of shortmostliked">
            <img [src]="liked.banner" alt="Banner">
          </div>
        </slick-slider-three>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!shortmostliked">
        <!-- Pre load -->
          <loader></loader>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <!--<slick-slider-three [shortfilms]=tag></slick-slider-three>-->
      <!--<h3>Most Watched</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>-->
      <div *ngIf="shortwatched">
        <slick-slider-three class="slick-slider">
          <div *ngFor="let film of shortwatched">
            <img [src]="film.banner" alt="Banner">
          </div>
        </slick-slider-three>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="!shortwatched">
        <!-- Pre load -->
          <loader></loader>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and Component's code is

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {ShortfilmsService} from './shortfilms.service';

@Component({
    selector:'app-shortfilms',
    templateUrl:'./shortfilms.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./shortfilms.component.css'],
    providers:[ShortfilmsService]
})

export class ShortfilmsComponent implements OnInit {
    public shortfilmslatest:Array<Object>;
    public shortmostliked:Array<Object>;
    public shortwatched:Array<Object>;

    constructor(private films: ShortfilmsService){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        // Enable First Tab
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu1"]').tab('show');
        });

        // Call function
        this.onPageLoad();
    }

    shortLatest(){
        this.shortfilmslatest = this.films.getMovieDetail();
    }

    shortMostLiked(){
        this.shortmostliked = this.films.getMovieDetail();
    }

    shortMostWatched(){
        this.shortwatched = this.films.getMovieDetail();
    }

    onPageLoad(){
        this.shortfilmslatest = this.films.getMovieDetail();
    }

}
```

What i am facing is when page loads the first time **Latest** tab activated automatically and shows slick slider in correct way but when i click on second tab it should show second slider but i am getting Error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./ShortfilmsComponent class ShortfilmsComponent - inline template:35:8 caused by: Cannot read property 'add' of null
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:56 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'add' of null
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:56
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:60 TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
    at c.b.initADA (eval at webpackJsonp.327.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:1), <anonymous>:17:18995)
    at c.b.init (eval at webpackJsonp.327.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:1), <anonymous>:17:18886)
    at new c (eval at webpackJsonp.327.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:1), <anonymous>:17:2931)
    at r.fn.init.a.fn.slick (eval at webpackJsonp.327.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:1), <anonymous>:18:9395)
    at SlickThreeComponent.webpackJsonp.701.SlickThreeComponent.ngAfterViewInit (slick-three.component.ts:20)
    at View_ShortfilmsComponent4.detectChangesInternal (/HomeModule/ShortfilmsComponent/component.ngfactory.js:297)
    at View_ShortfilmsComponent4.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
    at View_ShortfilmsComponent4.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:67)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ShortfilmsComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/HomeModule/ShortfilmsComponent/component.ngfactory.js:811)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (view.js:410)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_HomeComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/HomeModule/HomeComponent/component.ngfactory.js:126)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:60
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:63 ERROR CONTEXT:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:63
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:64 DebugContext {_view: View_ShortfilmsComponent4, _nodeIndex: 2, _tplRow: 35, _tplCol: 8}
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:64
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught ViewWrappedError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in ./ShortfilmsComponent class ShortfilmsComponent - inline template:35:8 caused by: Ca…, _nativeError: ZoneAwareError, originalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
    at c.b.initADA (eval at webpackJsonp.327.module.ex…, context: DebugContext, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Error in ./ShortfilmsComponent class Shortf…HomeModule/HomeComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)"…}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I really wouldn't use jQuery and "native" twitter bootstrap in Angular. Please have a look at [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap). BTW search for `initADA` method in your code and have a look at `.add`.

Comment: I am using ngAfterInit module where i can find initADA

Comment: So how should we help you when you don't show us the code? And still consider removing your code and replace it with ng2-bootstrap.

Comment: Whats the problem with approach ??

Comment: I used ng2-bootstrap but still getting same error

Comment: Again: how should we help you when you don't show us the code? I mean the code where initADA is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135287/discussion-between-sahadev-and-hgoebl).